# How do I deal with Conflicting JavaScripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with the calls below. (site is live at www.pushpinevents.com/alarm)
jkmegamenu.js seems to be conflicting with slides.js. Am I calling these scripts incorrectly?

Cheers!

```
<script src="java/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="java/slides.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="java/jkmegamenu.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor", "megamenu1", "mouseover")</script>
```

Comment: Conflicting how? Also, live sites are not very good test cases because of the sheer amounts of irrelevant clutter. Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a [pen](http://codepen.io/) or a page on your own hosting for more complicated examples. (Like those involving AJAX.

Comment: What are the actual errors your getting? Could it be that you are calling a selecter more than once?

Comment: remove `jQuery.noConflict();` from `jkmegamenu.js`

Comment: Contact the scripts authors and ask them to fix such bugs

Comment: Wrap your code in `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);)` or better yet, use `jQuery(function($) { ... });` to run it in the `ready` event.

Comment: jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#slides").slidesjs({... should be ok, in this case...

Comment: (Honestly, why the everloving \*bleep\* is a library calling `$.noConflict()`. And why aren't the functions plugin methods. I'd consider just using something that's coded less stupidly / better following jQuery conventions.)

Comment: Also, I'm confused why you're putting your javascript under a folder called java. JavaScript != Java.

Comment: I'm a noob I guess :D

Answer (score 0):

remove jQuery.noConflict(); from jkmegamenu.js – Dave Chen 5 mins ago

- This worked, thnx